LAN communication with WSL2
I have ROS2 Humble installed in a Ubuntu 22.04 PC, and WSL2 on my Windows 11. I want to make them communicate together, but I didn't succeed with basic talker/listener. How to achieve that?
I tried several things, first what is on the Microsoft website, with port proxy. But I don't know if I should use a specific port so I tried first with 4000, and then with two others recommended by ChatGPT (I also opened the ports on my Windows Defender Firewall):
Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
0.0.0.0         4000        192.168.199.165 4000
0.0.0.0         7400        192.168.199.165 7400
0.0.0.0         7600        192.168.199.165 7600

This IP address is the one of my WSL on eth0.
If I ping the Ubuntu PC (192.168.11.15) from my WSL it works, when I ping the Windows PC (192.168.11.50) from the Ubuntu PC it works too. However when I try ros2 multicast send/receive in both way from WSL2 and Ubuntu PC, as well as talker/listener, it is not communicating.
Moreover, I have only Windows 11 Home, so I cannot use Hyper-V manager to set the connection type.
I also tried with CycloneDDS, bu I am not sure if I set the config parameters well.
Here on WSL:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS>
  <Domain>
    <General>
      <NetworkInterfaceAddress>192.168.199.165</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
      <AllowMulticast>true</AllowMulticast>
    </General>
  </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>

and Ubuntu PC:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS>
  <Domain>
    <General>
      <NetworkInterfaceAddress>192.168.11.15</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
      <AllowMulticast>true</AllowMulticast>
    </General>
  </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>

What should I do to allow the communication of ROS though WSL2?
